# Removing ads in facebook canvas app/ page

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

I am creating a facebook canvas app and I was wondering if its possible to manage the ads displayed to the right of the app.

Maybe remove the ads, or choosing which one can be displayed.

I am using the facebook php sdk and js sdk. I can not find within the documentation any usefull function to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Facebook doesn't offers control on their ads on any area to anyone directly or indirectly through apps.** They manage their ads their own.

Currently it's not possible to remove the ads, or choosing which one can be displayed. And I don't think in future they will be giving permissions for other users. Canvas page is loaded on Facebook hence we can't remove it. Facebook earning lot of money through ads. They won't allow anyone to manage their ads.